# Is it possible to get exactly what the error is in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm getting an error when trying to add a foreign key and the description is not helpful at all: it's error 1050 and all I'm able to find in Google are [pages](http://verysimple.com/2006/10/22/mysql-error-number-1005-cant-create-table-mydbsql-328_45frm-errno-150/) with *a list of possible* causes. Is there a way to get the exact cause of an error from mysql, for example "fields do not match (one is unsigned and another is signed) so you can't have a foreign key"?

Comment: could you give an outline of the tables (and columns) involved and ofcourse the sql you are using to add the foreign key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run `show engine innodb status\G` at the MySQL prompt and look for the "LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR" section, that should give you more detail on the error.

Comment: Thanks man, I'm ashamed to admit I've been hating such mysql error messages for years and now it seems that's going to change :) This time I've got "You have defined a SET NULL condition though some of the columns are defined as NOT NULL.", which is exactly what I was looking for!